# Разработка web сайтов на html+php+js или ASP.NET?

Tags: php, javascript, html, .net, asp.net

Подскажите пожалуйста, как предпочтителнее, какие есть плюсы и минусы, что сейчас в тренде - *разработка web сайтов на html+php+js* **или** *ASP.NET*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# дороже в обслуживании. Так же на C# сайты цены дороже.Все зависит от решаемой задачи. Если делать уникальное решение, то стоит на C#. Если сайт визитку, то PHP.

Comment: Спасибо. Думаю что на C# более сложнее.

Comment: Не будет. Установить в IIS может быть будет сложнее. Это не папку кинуть в public_html. А программку составлять на c# куда приятнее этого вшивого php.

Comment: @Sergey нет в C# никакой "установки в IIS". Закидываешь файы и все работает. Причем кнопка "закинуть" прямо в студии есть.

Comment: @PashaPash Хорошо тогда раз так.

Comment: Разве на шарпе можно реализовать эффекты как на js? Что значит уникальное решение?

Comment: В C# можно использовать javascript+xml. Все тоже самое. Просто если пишешь сервис, то это намного проще.